# Using sys.argv variable in the python console

Tags: python

I would like to use the python terminal to run a certain script with a parameter. My actual example is more sophisticated but for reproducing purposes let's say I have a function called "test.py" that looks like this:

```
import sys
arg1 = sys.argv[1]

def printThat(arg1):
 print(arg1)
```

Now I open up my terminal and import "test.py"

```
>>> import test
```

However I cant seem to find how I can pass in a parameter? Could anybody tell me how I can pass in a parameter in the terminal?

Comment: `python test.py arg1`

Comment: What he means is when importing the module in the interpreter, and no that is not possible

Comment: `argv` is for command line parameters when executing the script directly. Importing it is a completely different matter, you pass arguments when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
arg1 = sys.argv[1]

def printThat(arg1):
    print(arg1)

printThat (arg1)
```

or simply:

```
import sys
print (sys.argv [1])
```